# javascript showing old events

Tags: javascript, events

I am having some trouble with javascript event handling. In my application I have an event which makes external xml requests and gives a responce to my event listener. This is allowed to happen many times to the same event listener. My event listener is repeating functions for old copies of my event and repeating all of my functions on each of them. 
Here is my code:

```
    document.addEventListener("data", getRemoteDataEvent, false);

    function getRemoteDataEvent(event){
    console.log(event);
    if(event.success===false){
        console.log(event);
        alert("error obtaining remote data");
    } else if(event.response != "<query_result></query_result>"){
        var xml = $.parseXML(event.response);
        parseThis(xml);
    }  else if(event.response == "<query_result></query_result>"){
        console.log(event.response);
        alert("Sorry, we have not yet come to your area");
    }
}
```

has anyone else run into this issue before?

edit: to show the remaining bits of my function. noting too important here, however do you see me missing a step in handling this?

Comment: I assume the function isn't console.log, so perhaps you can provide the real function and adding of the listener so we can see whats really happening

Comment: done, thanks is there anything else? this function really doesn't do much on it's own.

Comment: Its not the parsethis which is happening again, is it?

Comment: And you only add this listener once? Not each time you send the request?

Comment: that was the problem. if you want credit for answering just submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably adding the event listener each time you send the request. If you do, you should remove the listener when it finally runs, or just add it once.